# alarm Escaping Perl 'eval' block

Tags: perl, eval, lwp

I have a Perl script that automatically downloads content from various sources. It does the downloading in an `eval` block with an `alarm` so that the attempt will time out if it takes too long:

```
eval {
    alarm(5);
    my $res = $ua->request($req);
    $status = $res->is_success;
    $rawContent = $res->content;    
    $httpCode = $res->code;
    alarm(0);       
};
```

This has worked for years, but after doing some system updates, all of a sudden it quit working. Instead, the first source it hits that times out, I get the following error and the program terminates:

```
 Alarm clock
```

What am I doing incorrectly that is preventing `eval` from catching the alarm all of a sudden?

Comment: "some system updates" - Care to elucidate?

Comment: If you're using [LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent) then it's probably best to set `$ua->timeout(5)` rather than using  [`alarm`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm.html)

Comment: *"This has worked for years, but after doing some system updates, all of a sudden it quit working"* I think @Amias will be interested in this

Comment: @tjd I did a relatively significant number of updates using yum and also cPanel/WHM (it is a web hosting environment). Unfortunately, I don't have a list of everything that was updated.

Comment: @Borodin, I can't remember my reasoning for using alarm when I first wrote this. Perhaps I should explore that again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default for SIGALRM is to terminate the program, so you need to handle it.  A common way is to issue a `die` when SIGALRM is caught, turning it into an exception, which is `eval`-ed.

```
eval {
    local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "Timed out" };
    alarm(5);
    my $res = $ua->request($req);
    $status = $res->is_success;
    $rawContent = $res->content;    
    $httpCode = $res->code;
    alarm(0);       
};
if ($@ and $@ !~ /Timed out/) { die }  # re-raise if it is other error
```

From [Signals in `perlipc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Signals)

> Signal handling is also used for timeouts in Unix,   While safely protected within an `eval{}` block, you set a signal handler to trap alarm signals and then schedule to have one delivered to you in some number of seconds.  Then try your blocking operation, clearing the alarm when it’s done but not before you’ve exited your `eval{}` block.  If it goes off, you’ll use die() to jump out of the block, much as you might using longjmp() or throw() in other languages.

---

As for how it ever worked, the one thing I can think of is that packages used inside `eval` had their own timers, based on `alarm`, thus canceling your `alarm`. From [`alarm`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm.html)

> Only one timer may be counting at once.  Each call disables the previous timer, and an argument of 0 may be supplied to cancel the previous timer without starting a new one.

They may have thrown exceptions when timing out and you had the expected behavior. This package behavior changed in the update and now your alarm works and needs handling.  This is a guess, of course.

Comment: That worked -- the program sprang back to life! Thank you, @zdim! Any idea why it never would have caused a problem until now?

Comment: @TimothyR.Butler  I'm scratching my head about that right now ... Just what did you have there until now? Or -- did the code inside `eval` change? One shouldn't use multiple alarms at the same time, nor any other calls implemented via them (like sleep).

Comment: @TimothyR.Butler  The best I can think of is that packages used inside `eval` changed their behavior due to updates. They may have had their own timers which canceled your alarm, and now they don't.