# Perl Host to Ip Resolution

Tags: perl, gethostbyname

I am wanting to resolve a host name to an ip address which is all fine using Socket with the following:

```
$ip = gethostbyname($host) or die "Can't resolve ip for $host.\n";
$ip = inet_ntoa(inet_aton($host));
```

This works fine until it hits a host name that no longer resolves to an IP and the code just stops.  How can I get my script to continue processing the remainder ip the host names to be resolved.
Ideally I would simply set the `$ip` variable to equal `""`.

I have tried even without the die command and the code still stops when it cannot resolve the name to ip.

Comment: Try it with `eval`

Answer (score 3):

The timeout on `gethostbyname` is very, very long.  I assume that you kill the program before you can see that it is just taking a long time. It seems that you really need a shorter timeout.<sup>†</sup>

You can set up your own timer using [alarm](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm.html). When it goes off a SIGALRM signal is delivered to the process, which would terminate it by default. So we set up a handler for that signal in which a `die` is issued, thus turning it into an exception. This is `eval`-ed and we get the control back.

```
eval {
    local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "Timed out" };

    alarm 5;  # or what you find most suitable

    # your code that may need a timeout

    alarm 0;
};
if ($@ and $@ !~ /Timed out/) { die }  # re-raise if it was something else

if ($@ and $@ =~ /Timed out/) {  # test
    print "We timed out\n";
}
```

If your code completes in less than `5` seconds we get to `alarm 0;` which cancels the previous alarm and the program continues.  Otherwise the `SIGALRM` is emitted, but is handled and made into a `die` which is `eval`-ed, and so altogether the signal is caught and the control drops to right after the block. We test whether the `die` was indeed due to our alarm and if not we re-raise it.

Also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37817494/4653379) for more comments, and please search for more.

---

<sup>†</sup>   The `Timeout` functionality that exists in the module `IO::Socket` is for connect and not for the DNS lookup, which is the culprit here. Thanks to [Steffen Ullrich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3081018/steffen-ullrich) for a comment.

Comment: The timeout in IO::Socket::* is only for socket activity, i.e. connect. It does not include the DNS lookup which is done blocking using gethostbyname or gethostbyaddr.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich  Thank you! I saw that somewhere but wasn't sure. Edited to the post.